# placing subcaptions of subfloats at thir right side

Tags: latex

How can I place subcaptions of subfloats (subfigures) on their right side?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to explore the [sidecap package](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Side_captions). Whether it behaves nicely with subfigures, I don't know...

Comment: It doesn't look like it from the documentation.

Comment: I just tried it. It does exactly what the OP wants, regardless of what the README says. (that is, it works for figures. I can't be bothered hacking together an example with subfigures right now)

Answer (score 0):

You could put your `subfig` next to a `minipage` with the graphic.

For example:

```
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \graphic
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}{1in}
        \begin{subfloat}[This is a caption]
        ~
        \end{subfloat}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Where `\graphic` is a placeholder for your image (I used `\def\graphic{\rule{1in}{1in}}`)

I don't know how to ensure that the empty sub-float gives enough space for the caption, however.